# reading timestampcounter showing strange values

Tags: c, linux, rdtsc

I have the following C file rdtsc.c that demonstrates the use of rdtsc() in C.I have conditional compile for both 64-bit versions and 32-bit versions.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#ifdef X86_64
static inline unsigned long long tick()
{

    unsigned long low, high;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a" (low), "=d" (high));
    return ((unsigned long long)high << 32) | low);
}
#else
static inline unsigned long long tick()
{
     unsigned long long d;
     __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=A" (d) );
     return d;
}
#endif

int main()
{
        long long res;
        volatile int a = 1;
        volatile int b = 3;
        volatile int c = 0;
        res=tick();
        c = (a + b)*11000;
        res=tick()-res;
        printf("ticks %lld",res);
        return 0;
}
```

I run the above program in a loop from the shell as shown below.

```
for i in {1..10} ; do { ./a.out ; printf "\n"; } ; done
```

The output that I get is given below.

```
ticks 96
ticks 108
ticks 8698
ticks 8613
ticks 108
ticks 84
ticks 96
ticks 108
ticks 96
ticks 96
```

Since the same operation is being done.I would certainly expect the values to be more urniform.How do I account for this disparity in the values?

Comment: Multitasking. Your process is not the only one on the system.

Comment: Wait, `X86_64` is defined when compiling 32-bit?

Comment: How do I easily lock those three instructions to make sure that this does not happen?

Comment: @Medinoc - why are you saying that? As far as I understand the first function is for a 64-bit system and the second function is for a 32-bit system.

Comment: Because I see the first function read a 64-bit value through two registers, and the second function read it through one register. I may be reading wrong because I don't know the `__asm__` syntax very well, but to me it looks like the functions were swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multitasking should indeed be the answer.
When you get higher values (~9000) your process gets preempted. Looking at the values with this in mind they will seem uniform.

Answer (score 1):

On multicore-CPU platform, 'TSC' must be firstly synchronization.

You can use `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`

Reference http://lwn.net/Articles/211051